# Does AMF support caching?

Tags: apache-flex, flash, caching, amf, http-status-code-304

In other words: Can I respond with a 304 and have it "just work"?

Comment: Isn't AMF a binary data format?  How can a format support caching?  I believe if you want to cache data, you'll have to implement such caching mechanisms yourself.

Comment: Yes, AMF is a binary format, but it is transported via HTTP - which means I should be able to use built-in browser caching using HTTP headers to control expiration. I'm just not sure if this works with any of the AMF libraries.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By default Flex's RemoteObject and BlazeDS handle AMF requests as POSTs so they won't cache in the browser.  You could change that by implementing your own servlet that serializes GET responses as AMF.  Then on the Flex side use URLLoader to make the request.  That might cause the browser to cache the response.